# How could Kayin have married his sister, if it was prohibited?

Tags: marriage, rambam, parashat-bereishit, giluy-arayos

The Rambam writes in Melachim uMilchamot ([Ch. 9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm)) that six different mitzvot were given to Adam. One of these mitzvot is the prohibition of incest and adultery.

The Gemara ([Sanhedrin 38b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=38b&format=pdf)) says that Kayin married his twin sister. (Rashi explains how we know Kayin had a twin sister in his comments to Bereishit 4:1.)

How would this be permitted, considering the prohibition of incest was given to Adam?

Similarly, in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23349/11486) brought elsewhere, Ibn Ezra taught that in the early generations each son was born with a twin sister whom he would marry. This just furthers my question.

(For the general question of *Who was Kayin's wife?* see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/who-was-cains-wife).)

Comment: I vaguely remember it being said that in the first generations, as there were no real options for both obeying the prohibition and procreating, people were allowed to marry their _Isurei Arayot_ (a sort of _Hora'at Sha'a_), so that the world could be populated.  This is supposed to be alluded to in the verse (_Tehilim_ 89:3) "_Olam Chesed Yibaneh_". Maybe try [Sanhedrin 58b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=58b&format=pdf).

Comment: Where in Sanhedrin 38b does it say that he married her?

Comment: @Alex I think he's basing that on [Yehuda's answer there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23352/1368). Why not ask him?

Comment: @TamirEvan Ask Yehuda? According to his profile he hasn't been here in almost a year. Besides, the questioner here quotes the Gemara as a source before he ever mentioned the other answer.

Comment: @TamirEvan And that answer also doesn't show where the Gemara says this. It just quotes R. Chaim Kanievski as the source that the Gemara says this. If you look at R. Kanievski's words, I don't think he's even necessarily saying that.

Answer (score 8):

Yerushalmi Yevamos 11:1 (quoted by Rashi to Vayikra 20:17):

> "אמר רבי אבין, שלא תאמר קין נשא את אחותו, הבל נשא את אחותו, חסד הוא, חסד עשיתי עם הראשונים שייבנה העולם מהן, כי אמרתי עולם חסד יבנה"
>
> Said Rebi Avin, one should not say, "Kayin married his sister, Hevel married his sister [and therefore it cannot be sinful]," [rather] "it was a kindness," (Vayikra 20:17), a kindness that I [God] performed for the early ones so that the world should be built from them, "for I have said the world should be built with kindness" (Tehillim 89:3)

Thus, the understanding of Chazal is that there was a one-generation suspension of this law of incest for the good of humanity.

Some understood (based on kabbalistic principles which I do not understand) that the *reason* for the incest prohibition would not be applicable to Adam's first generation descendants.

Rakanati to Vayikra 18:6 posits:

> טעם איסור העריות אין לבעלי הקבלה דבר מקובל בו. רק קצתם אמרו כי הטעם שלא להשיב דבר הנפרד לשרשו והענף לעקרו כי מאחר שאנחנו כולנו סבה אחר סבה נמצאים זה מזה אין לעשות הענפים המתפשטים אילך ואילך שורש בפני עצמו כי הקרובים הם הענפים המתפשטים מן השורש ויש להם לקבל לחות מן הענפים אחרים לא מעצמם כי היה מתייבש. והבא על הערוה גורם יבשות הענף ההוא מהמרכבה עליונה אבל קין לא נאסר באחותו כי לא היו סבה אחר סבה כי מכח עליון נוצרו ז' כנגד ז' ימי בראשית. ויש מן האחרונים שאמרו בסוד העריות כי הטעם הוא כטעם סוד העבור שלא יכרת שם המת ממשפחתו וראה הש"י ברוב חכמתו איזה מקום מנוחתו ואמרו לקרוביו כי לפעמים יבא בזכר ואם לא זכה יבא בנקבה ושמא יבא על אביו ובנו ואחיו ודודו וזה טעם ערות אביך וערות אחי אביך המדבר בזכרים

Similarly, Derashot R. Yehoshua ibn Shuiab to Acharei-Mos, Kedoshim:

> והכלל כי כל הבא על אחת מכל אלו העריות הוא מכחיש
> במעשה בראשית, כמו שכתב רבי עזרא ז׳׳ל שלא להשיב דבר הנפרד לשורשו והענף לעיקרו,
> אולם האחים שנבראו בששת ימי בראשית הן דוגמת שבע המעיינות, ולכן הותרו בתאומותיהן,
> וזהו חסד הוא

<sub>Although the Gemara quoted in the question (Sanhedrin 38b) does not say so explicitly, Tosfos there certainly understand that Kayin and Hevel were each born with a twin sister, who they presumably married. Additionally, the Mishnah (Sanhedrin 4:5, Bavli 38a) writes that אדם נברא יחידי, strongly implying that there are no human beings descendent from anyone else.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

R. Abraham of Viterbo writes the following in [Sefer Emunas Chachamim Essay # 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43991&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=)

> והנה לא ספרה התורה קין והבל שני בני אדם וחוה את מי נשאו לנשים כיון
>   שהעולם היה שומם ולא היו שם כי אם הם לבדם והתורניים אמרו כי בני אדם
>   הראשון נולדו עם זווגיהן גם חכמי הנוצרים ככה אמרו וכן באמת דעת חכמי
>   התלמוד שאמרו תאומים נולדו עם קין והבל ואם קבלה נקבל ולפי הנראה משקול
>   הדעת אינו נראה כן כי לפי דבריהם אנו כולנו בני ממזרים שנולדו מזיוג נפסד
>   נתעב ונאלח ויותר טוב לומר שהקב"ה נתן להם נשים עשעם בכבודו ובעצמו מפני
>   הצורך כמו שעשה לחוה זהו דעתי בדבר הזה אעפ"י שאין לי ראיה והרוצה לחלוק
>   עלי יחלוק
>
> Behold the Torah does not tell us who Cain and Abel, the two sons of
>   Adam and Eve, married, since the world was desolate and there was no
>   one there except themselves. The Torah-people say that the sons of
>   Adam-the-first-man were born with their mates; the Christian scholars
>   say this as well, and in truth this is the opinion of the Sages of the
>   Talmud – they said that twins were born with Cain and Abel. If this is
>   a tradition we accept it, but from an intellectual assessment this
>   does not appear to be the case. For according to this we are all the
>   children of bastards, as they were born from a contaminated,
>   despicable, inferior union. It is better to say that God gave them
>   women [that] He Himself made due to the need, just like he did with
>   Eve. This is my opinion on this matter even though I have no proof,
>   and whoever wants to disagree with me can disagree.